# instancing an distributing points in geometry nodes. The mesh I'm instancing on shows up in viewport, but not final render. Is my join geometry wrong?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to distribute a sesame seed mesh on a bun. I can get my instance to show, and my original mesh I'm distributing the instance on shows in the viewport after the join geometry node is added. However, I can't get "the bun" to appear in the render (cycles or evee).Only the instance renders.

Where am I going wrong here? I went into the object data just to triple check and it looks like render and viewport is enabled. All transforms are applied just incase.
https://pasteall.org/blend/c2688e6493a24d288509bece57ef9220

heres the file^^
[image]

Comment: maybe you didn't click the camera icon in outliner? if this doesn't help, provide blend file, so we can check it out. The reason is not in the geometry nodes tree

Comment: Camera seems good... https://pasteall.org/blend/c2688e6493a24d288509bece57ef9220 Heres the file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a realize instances after join geometry

[image]

Comment: This is very strange. Have any idea why the unrealized mesh isn't showing and why realizing it fixes it?

Comment: @Benus: You are right and i have no idea why it is that way - but it works ;) ...might be  a bug

Comment: Thank you other Chris!

Comment: You are welcome. Please click on the checkmark left to my answer, if this helped you. Thanks!